# When adding Facebook sdk as library project other libraries are not recognised by eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am integrating Facebook sdk for social login to my app. Fo that I created one separate app first and made sure everything working fine. After that when I am trying to do same with my app I am getting compilation errors.

As soon as I include Facebook sdk as library project to my project, other imports being used in my project become unrecognized:

```
import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
import org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries;
import org.achartengine.model.MultipleCategorySeries;
import org.achartengine.model.TimeSeries;
```

I tried including facebooksdk.jar to accomplish this task. This way I did not get any compilation error, but now application crashes at run time saying :

```
01-14 14:56:57.092: E/AndroidRuntime(12753): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.app/com.test.app.ui.login.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
...
01-14 14:56:57.092: E/AndroidRuntime(12753): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
...
```

Project.properties:

## Project target.

```
target=android-21

    android.library.reference.3=../FlowLayout
    android.library.reference.4=../library
    android.library.reference.1=../AndroidUtils
    android.library.reference.2=../AudioPlayer
    android.library.reference.6=../Scribble
    android.library.reference.5=../StoryRenderer
    android.library.reference.8=../VO
    android.library.reference.7=../Service
    android.library.reference.9=../Keyboard
    android.library.reference.10=../EventManager
    android.library.reference.11=../HoloGraphLibrary
    android.library.reference.12=../../../android-sdks/extras/android/support/multidex/library
    android.library.reference.13=../../../Downloads/facebook-android-sdk-3.22.0/facebook
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: attach screen shot of project properties of your project

Comment: I just realised, as soon as I add facebook sdk as library project, AndroidPrivateLibrary is being removed from project.

Comment: Any solution people out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. I included FB Sdk as library project. FB SDK was also having android-support-v4.jar and my project was also having that. So this conflict made private libraries removed.(Do not know why.)

So I removed android-support-v4.jar from Facebook SDK and refered already existing one which resolved my problem.